# Css Media Print, table goes to new page

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a dynamic table with some test just before it, I am having some problems printing this (on actual paper), sometimes the table starts in the new page, so my first page is just the header test and then the table on the second. I have tried with `page-break-before: always;` and several possible combinations of the `page-break` properties without luck.

Does anyone know how can I force the table to start printing right at where it is on the page?

Forgive the bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a perfect solution, but if your header is in a `div`, you could just hide that `div` when `print()` is called...

```
<div id="header">Your header is here</div>
<div>Your table/content goes here</div>

@media print {
#header {
    display: none;
}}
```